# export chart to image high quality

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, image-processing, charts

I am exporting a chart fx into image, but this image have a low quality.

```
Chart chart1 = new Chart();
```

.
.
.

```
chart1.Export(FileFormat.Bitmap, "C:/WcfSReport/WcfSReport/WcfSReport/image.bmp");
```

Does anyone know how I can export this chart into an high quality image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try and use `FileFormat.Metafile`